# CMake: Reference external library from static library

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14

I've C++ project build using CMake and currently facing 1 issue, brief description below

**lib_common -- STATIC library**
lib common uses libconfig to load common configurations used in other project.

**script_executor -- CMake project**
It references above static library and also add external library libconfig, see below:

```
add_executable(script_executor)
target_link_libraries(script_executor "-lconfig++" "-llibcommon")
```

So I'm referencing llibcommon inside this project and llibcommon also uses libconfig which is already reference("-lconfig++") from this project.

But I'm still getting  undefined reference to `libconfig::Config::Config()`

**Environment details:**

- UBuntu 16.04,
- cmake version 3.5.1,
- gcc version 5.4.0,
- g++ version 5.4.0

Comment: try changing library order putting `-lconfig++` after `-llibcommon`, also `llibcommon` can probably be `lcommon`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.